# I Learned a New Word Today

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, pattern

> To start the day off, I went for a swim
>   Then dug up a tuber with vigor and vim.
>   I scored it as 10. It was proper and prim.
>   A relative came. One clue: it's a him.
>   A movie with guns, hats and horses entwined.
>   Another kin came, of the feminine kind.
>   I looked at my watch: I was running behind
>   I loathe and despise that! Dislike filled my mind!
>   But with a quick snack- a reversal of mood.
>   I called up a friend. I romanced her and wooed.
>   I filled up a hall with drinks, tables and food...
>   Took lime from a hide??? What's this word I have clued?

Can you guess the obscure five letter English word I learned today?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution:

> **Bater**

Explanation:

> The pattern here that these are all definitions for 5-letter words that end in **-ater**:
>
>  01. **Water** [*"went for a swim"*]
>  02. **Tater** [*"tuber"*]
>  03. **Rater** [*"scored it"*]
>  04. **Pater** [Male relative]
>  05. **Oater** [A western]
>  06. **Mater** [Female relative]
>  07. **Later** [*"running behind"*]
>  08. **Hater** [*"I loathe and despise"*]
>  09. **Eater** [*"with a quick snack"*]
>  10. **Dater** [*"romanced her and wooed"*]
>  11. **Cater** [Fill up a hall with tables and food]
>  12. **Bater** [A tanner removing lime from a hide]
>
>  ...With the 12th word being the obscure one the OP just learned. :)
>  *[The words are also sorted in a reverse alphabetical order, to make the pattern more obvious.]*

Comment: Actually, that’s it (the alternative direction)! I was going for the last word in the sequence: a word I’ve never come across before. I figured most people wouldn’t know it so I arranged the valid words reverse alphabetically so people could find it. Well done!

Comment: @HughMeyers Ah, I see! I did notice the reverse alphabetical order, but no. 9 was in the way. So I'm assuming 9 is really rot13(rngre)? [I'll re-edit]

Comment: Oh. Yes, that’s right. Doh! Should have looked more carefully. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this site and especially to these type of questions,so if my answer seems stupid or wrong please explain in the comments so that I will learn!

**Now, coming to the question:**

> I'm basically relating your single day to general terms in a person's life:

**Sentence 1:**

> Exercise/fitness.

**Sentence 2:**

> Food

**Sentence 3:**

> Satisfied/happy mindset

**Sentence 4:**

> Being social

**Sentence 5:**

> Spending time with family/being social

**Sentence 6:**

> Being social again

**Sentence 7 and 8:**

> Regret/sad

**Sentence 9:**

> I'm back/back from being sad/refreshment/Happy again

**Sentence 10:**

> Something like finding a mate

**Sentence 11:**

> Food and being with family/being social

**Together:**

> You are probably talking about life because all the above mentioned things are a part of a person's life... so at the end of the day you might be thinking that this is life

**So, the word is:**

> **LIFE**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to puzzling! There's nothing wrong with your reasoning, so that's good. We usually put "spoiler tags" in answers so that they are hidden until you hover over them. You do this by adding "!> " at the beginning of a line. This riddle has a "Pattern" tag, meaning that there is a sequence to be solved. That's one of the keys here. Also, if a puzzle is correctly constructed the answer should be unambiguous. The answer you give, although it fits, is rather general. But good work. Keep puzzling!

Comment: @HughMeyers...When would the answer be revealed?

Comment: The answer is revealed when someone guesses it. The correct answer is marked with a green check mark by the poster. Sometimes this takes days. Ah. And I got the spoiler tag backwards. It is ">! ". I edited your answer to spoiler tag the last line.

Comment: If no one guesses for a while, posters sometimes add hints (usually with spoiler tags).

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

> There is a 'pattern' of *alliteration* in the poem (eg "Vigor and Vim", "Proper and Prim")

Perhaps:

> To **s**tart the day off, I went for a **s**wim
>  Then dug up a tuber with **v**igor and **v**im.
>  I scored it as 10. It was **p**roper and **p**rim.
>  A relative **c**ame. One **c**lue: it's a him.
>  A movie with guns, **h**ats and **h**orses entwined.
>  Another **k**in came, of the feminine **k**ind.
>  **I** looked at my watch: **I** was running behind
>  I loathe and **d**espise that! **D**islike filled my mind!
>  But with **a** quick snack- **a** reversal of mood.
>  I called up **a** friend. I romanced her **a**nd wooed.
>  I filled up **a** hall with drinks, tables **a**nd food...
>  **T**ook lime from a hide??? What's **t**his word I have clued?

But I'm struggling for an answer because:

> I'm looking for just one word, and the longest word I can make out of the letters **svpchkidaaat** is a 10 letter one - "kadaitchas", tribal men with the mission of avenging the death of a tribesman. Well you did say it was obscure.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

To start the day off, I went for a swim

> 

Then dug up a tuber with vigor and vim.

> Potato/Yam?

I scored it as 10. It was proper and prim.

> 

A relative came. One clue: it's a him.

> 

A movie with guns, hats and horses entwined.

> Cowboy? Western?

Another kin came, of the feminine kind.

> 

I looked at my watch: I was running behind

> Late

I loathe and despise that! Dislike filled my mind!

> Hate

But with a quick snack- a reversal of mood.

> Sate?

I called up a friend. I romanced her and wooed.

> Date

I filled up a hall with drinks, tables and food...

> 

Took lime from a hide??? What's this word I have clued?

> 

Mostly based on the fact that

> The answers in the second half all seem to rhyme. Not sure about the first half, though.

Comment: I can confirm that you are reaching in the right direction. You're not there yet but you're definitely getting warm.

Comment: Score 10 - perhaps RATE

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> As the word was "obscure" the answer need to obtained by acrostic?

Then:

Line 1

> Pool?

Line 7:

> Late?

Line 10:

> Date?

Line 11:

> Feast/ Waiter/ Waitress?

Answer (score 0):

My reasoning is much more simplistic.

5 letter english word that starts with the letters hide and makes sense in the sentence...

> hider

Comment: It seems like you are only taking into account the very last line of the puzzle and attempting to add a single letter where the "???" is. How does your solution fit with the rest of the puzzle?